# 256 Bit Encryption in Android (Using Rijndael algorithm)

Tags: android

How to perform 256 Bit AES Encryption (Using Rijndael algorithm).

*Requirement:* I have implemented 256 Bit Encryption (Rijndael) on server 
(using C#.Net) and it sends data to client (i.e Android device) - now 
to decrypt these data - would like to implement 256 Bit Encryption 
(Rijndael) on Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To decrypt the data successfully you have tio concern with

- which cipher mode the server is using eg ECB, CBC
- what is the initialization vector(iv) parameter that the server is using
- The key of encryption and decryption must be same
- what is the padding algorithm that the server used eg PKCS7

Comment: Thanks Deepak for prompt reply... Will check all these parameters used on server code and try to implement same on client.