# Safe connection between device and server

Tags: android, http

The app does not use login username/password feature.. assume whatsapp, or viber.

Howe do these devices make a secure connection to the server and fetch the data, in a way, that even someone else, found out the POSTed data and used them,  can not get the info ?

I am using HTTP.

It's a PHP server.

Answer (score 1):

This question is kind of open-ended. Secure communication is often device-independent, based on the protocol stack in use.

From lower- to higher-level:

- TCP connection: It may [implement SSL](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html).
- HTTP protocol: It may [implement HTTPS](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html).
- [GET/PUT operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163311/android-file-upload-using-http-put): You may implement reversible encryption on your payload, like [Rijndael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354393/256-bit-encryption-in-android-using-rijndael-algorithm). This way, if someone actually gets the POST data, it may be unreadable without the proper decrypt function.

Of course you may combine encryption implementations. Just remeber that you may be adding considerable overhead to the whole process.

Comment: I will mainly be requesting data from a server which might change for each user. What is the best approach. Someone told me `token generated auth`. Where does that fall ?

Comment: Authentication is a different kind of beast - it controls access to a resource, not encryption - and can't by itself prevent intercepted POST data from being interpreted. -Best- is a problematic word; it depends on your specific needs. Given that you don't want 3rd parties to see your POST content, I'd go with reversible encryption.

Comment: exactly. that's what I want. to control the access to a resource, aka the data inside the server to be fetched in this case. It's not that I don't want my posts to be seen. that's not a must. I just want to make sure if a person X wants to fetch data, someone else, - a bad person - should not be able to fetch the same data too using tools etc..

Comment: Ah, I see. So I agree with the person that mentioned token auth to you - it may be a viable way to anonymously identify a unique session.